# Angular model/controller "hierarchy" setup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, ngboilerplate

I am building an angular app that is essentially an admin panel for all my sites & their environments using ngboilerplate. I need to setup a kind of hierarchy of functions & model data such that any "child" controller/model doesn't work without the "parent" being set. Here is a breakdown of what I'm trying to explain.

model -> Environment (prod, stage, dev)
     once the env is selected you would then be able to select the site

model -> sites (all sites from
   current env)   once a site is selected you then get the site data

model -> site (site data json contains things like page configuration
   values and such)

What is the proper way to setup the structure for something like this? I am currently just using individual controllers & routes (ui-router) for each within route within the page. The main functionality I need to ensure is if the environment is changed with a site selected that the site's data be reload from the proper environment. I am thinking I would be using $watch to ensure that? Any suggestions/tips on best practices on appreciated!

UPDATE: to clarify here are some specifics:

The main model I need "watched" is the environment model. Depending on which env was set I would adjust the api url being used as well as change the display name. As well it would also load the corresponding sites list for the env (currently a static json file, but it could be an api call instead). Here is the code I wrote before asking this question, when I got the the SitesCtrl I realized I was probably doing it wrong (or not optimally anyway).

Tools.js

```
angular.module( 'SupportBase.tools', [
  'ui.router',
  'placeholders',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'SupportBase.tools.sites'
])

.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'tools', {
    url: '/tools',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'ToolsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'tools/tools.tpl.html'
      },
      "sites": {
        controller: 'SitesCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'tools/sites/sites.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Site Tools' }
  });
})

.controller( 'ToolsCtrl', function ToolCtrl( $scope ) {
  $scope.envModel = '';

});
```

Tools.tpl.hmtl

```
    <div class="row">
    <h1 class="page-header">
    Site Tools
    <small>For the lazy and impatient. {or the smart & productive}</small>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-md-5">
        <h4>Current Working Environment:
        <code class="env">{{envModel || 'null'}}</code></h4>
        <div class="btn-group col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="tools.sites({env: envModel})" ng-model="envModel" btn-radio="'Production'">Production</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="tools.sites({env: envModel})" ng-model="envModel" btn-radio="'Stage'">Stage</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="tools.sites({env: envModel})" ng-model="envModel" btn-radio="'QA'">QA</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="tools.sites({env: envModel})" ng-model="envModel" btn-radio="'Dev'">Dev</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" ui-view="sites"></div>
</div>
```

Sites.js

```
angular.module('SupportBase.tools.sites', [
    'ui.router',
    'placeholders',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'SupportBase.tools'
])

.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tools.sites', {
        url: '/{env:[a-z]{1,10}}/sites',
        views: {
            "sites": {
                controller: 'SitesCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'tools/sites/sites.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Site Tools | SupportBase'
        }
    });
})

.controller('SitesCtrl', function SitesCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $scope.env = $stateParams.env.toLowerCase();
    $scope.disabled = $stateParams.env !== '' ? false : true;
    if ($stateParams.env.toLowerCase() === 'production') {
        $http.get('./src/app/sites/sites.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.sitesModel = data;
        });
    } else {
        $scope.sitesModel = [$stateParams.env, 'something', 'face'];
    }


});
```

Sites.tpl.html

```
    <div class="well" collapse="disabled">
    <h1>Site Selector</h1>
    <h2>{{sitesModel}}</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use ui.router so I'll be very generic and you can apply as needed.

Also I have not tested this exact code so use it as a guide.

```
// setup constants to refer to and change when needed
.constant('site_config', {
    'api_path' : '//prod.example.com',
    'name' : 'Production',
    'collection' : '/production'
});




.controller( 'homepage_controller', function($scope, $location, $log, site_config, environment){

    var load_site = function() {
        $scope.title = site_config.name;
        environment.get().then(function(data){
            $log.log('Do something with this ',data)
        })
    }

    // looking for sandbox.example.com 
    if(window.location.host.indexOf('sandbox') > -1 ) {
        environment.set('prod').then(function(){
            $log.log('sandbox is loaded')
            load_site()
        })

    // looking for qa.example.com 
    } else if (window.location.host.indexOf('qa') > -1) {
        environment.set('qa').then(function(){
            $log.log('qa is loaded')
            load_site()
        })

    // looking for www.example.com 
    } else {
        environment.set('prod').then(function(){
            $log.log('production is loaded')
            load_site()
        })
    }

})





.factory('environment', function ($window, $q, $http, $log, $rootScope, site_config) { 
    var environment = {};

    environment.set = function(type) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if(type == 'sandbox') {
            site_config.api_path = '//sandbox.example.com';
            site_config.name = 'Sandbox';
            site_config.collection = '/development';
            deferred.resolve(true)
        }
        if(type == 'qa') {
            site_config.api_path = '//qa.example.com';
            site_config.name = 'QA';
            site_config.collection = '/qa';
            deferred.resolve(true)
        }
        if(type == 'production') {
            site_config.api_path = '//prod.example.com';
            site_config.name = 'Production';
            site_config.collection = '/production';
            deferred.resolve(true)
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // just showing this as an example
    environment.get = function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url: site_config.api_path+site_config.collection
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(false);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return environment;
})
```

Comment: This should get me going! Appreciate the help!

Comment: @JayVanderlyn  Just wanted to give you another shout out I got things working the way I need them. You not only helped me solve my current issue, but you helped get me to understand proper angularjs development. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Still a bit vague on what you're trying to do. Here is some code to get you started:

```
.constant('site_configuration', {
    'greeting' : 'Hello User'
});


.factory('environment', function ($window, $q, $http, $log, $rootScope, secondary_service, site_configuration) { 

    // this way your child functions can call each other within the factory
    var environment = {};
    environment.prod = function() {

    };

    environment.dev = function(credentials) {
        secondary_service.login(credentials).then(function(){
            $log.log('hello')
            site_configuration.greeting = 'Hello Dev Environment User!'
        })
    };

    environment.stage = function(credentials) {
    // do something
    }

    return environment;
})


.service('secondary_service', function ($window, $q, $log, $rootScope, $http) {
    var myservice = {};

    secondary_service.login = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // some http call
        deferred.resolve(true)

        return deferred.promise;
   };
   return myservice;
})
```

Comment: I definitely think I need to be using factories. I've added some detail to my question would you mind taking another look?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into factories? They are essentially a singleton pattern you can use as service layer. Each controller can depend on the same factory for its data and bind to it and when the data is changed the changes are updated universally